# Angular 8 npm install fails

Tags: angular8

I just recently upgraded to Angular 8 and my local build passing with aot. But in Jenkins build getting failed with below error. Can anyone help?

**Here is the error**

> npm install
>
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
>
> Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>
> npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
>
> npm WARN deprecated uws@9.148.0: New code is available at github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js
>
> npm ERR! path git
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn git
>
> npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
>
> npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/pemrouz/buble.git
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-25T10_05_09_308Z-debug.log

**here is my package json**

```
  "name": "olam-global-survey-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you upgrade angular 8 its installs all default packages with Bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 4 installs popper.js package which helps for tooltip
- Initial popper.js version will be ^1.0.1 and it is not supported with Angular 8 and Node 13. So we have to upgrade the package to version "popper.js": "^1.16.1"

Answer (score 0):

It's a npm cache problem. 
just find npm-cache folder and delete it,

open terminal in administrator mode or use sudo if your OS supports linux

or

use `npm clean-install`

Comment: how do i do that in jenkins? any suggestion to devops guys?

Comment: brother you must use pipelines in jenkins for this

Comment: bro in the jenkins pipeline only the build getting failed

Comment: `pipeline {
    agent any
 
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node 6.x', configId: '<config-file-provider-id>') {
                    sh 'npm clean-install'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`